Error when executing procedure to add columns to all tables
I have created a procedure to add a timestamp column to all the tables in my database. When I execute the procedure without tables it works correctly, but as soon as I create a test table and execute the procedure it gives me the following error:
"The following query failed: "CALL `add_timestamp_column_to_tables`(); "

MySQL said: #1064 - There is an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your version of MariaDB server to find out the correct syntax to use aro"

The procedure code is as follows:
-- Stored procedure to add timestamp column to all tables
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE add_timestamp_column_to_tables()
BEGIN
    DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

-- Get the name of all tables
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

-- Open cursor
    OPEN cur;

-- Loop to traverse all tables
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO table_name;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        -- ALTER TABLE statement to add the timestamp column
        SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `timestamp_column` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP;

  -- close cursor
    CLOSE cur;
END //

DELIMITER ;

What could be causing the error?
Thank you.

Comment PREPARE/EXEC/DROP but add SELECT @sql;. Call. Ensure that all returned query texts are correct. Add SET @statementno=N; after each SP statement, look the value after CALL - this allows to understand where the execution fails.

SELECT @sql; It always returns null. But if I do the select, only the tables appear.

t always returns null. This is strange.. what client do you use? if I do the select, only the tables appear Provide a sample of the output, 2-3 rows..

What is the error?

Try abbreviating your @sql with "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT......" as a single statement. Given "aro" isn't in your SQL what is the table name that has this string?

Add some debugging so we can see what the generated SQL looks like.

you have truncated the most important part of the error message.  please give the full error message

Use different name for the variable table_name. The variable is getting mixed with a column with the same name (information_schema.tables.table_name).
